# Why are values of complex integration different along different contours?

Tags: contour-integration

I integrated $f(z) = z$ conjugate on two different line segments

a) from $0$ to 1 then to $1 + i$
b) from $0$ to $1 + i$ directly

And I correctly obtained answers of $1 + i$ for a) and $1$ for b)

but why are the answers different

Comment: Are there any underlying principle that you expect complex integral shall obey?

Comment: Do you realize that we don't have path independence for line integrals of real-valued functions either?

Comment: Well, what reason is there to expect them to be the same?  You're effectively integrating two totally different functions, one of which is given by the values of $f$ on one path and one if which is given by the values of $f$ on another path.